# Load Unity game launch options from file

Tags: unity, loading, file, configuration

I have a need to disable the resolution dialogue when the game launches, but have a config file that will have all of the dialogue options (resolution, quality, monitor (monitor is most important, because none of the solutions to change the active monitor after launch have worked out with a decent result)). Is there a way for a unity game to load options from a file instead of the resolution dialogue?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with: saving and loading variable data to/from a file, or using variables to set your resolution, quality settings, and monitor through code?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to do it before the game runtime if possible. As for the runtime variant, I have problems changing the active monitor, it only works correctly for me if I choose the monitor in the resolution dialog before the game starts

Comment: @PaulVinogradov do you want to remove the launcher window when you run .exe on unity game?

Comment: @CandidMoon Yes. I know that you remove it in the "Show Resolution Dialog" option, I use "Hidden by default" atm. The main question is replacing it with a config file

Comment: @PaulVinogradov did you try to google it? Use some kind of JSON/XML/Binary file to store the data and just set it in the game when the game is loaded. "This question does not show any research effort." - try better next time. And it's poorly described as well, 2 people had to clarify what your question is about. I am still unsure if you know how to read/write from/to file. Or if you know the API to change settings in Unity.

Comment: @CandidMoon I know how to read from file, the question is about replacing the dialog functionality because the dialog sets the settings BEFORE the game is actually launched. If just setting everything at runtime worked, I wouldn't have this problem. But, as I said, the monitor switching only works when selecting the dialog. I have tried hard coding resolutions and the Unity SetActiveMonitor functions but they don't work properly when monitors are different, etc

Comment: @PaulVinogradov http://www.aclockworkberry.com/managing-screen-resolution-and-aspect-ratio-in-unity-3d/ - They are usually stored in PlayerPrefs. I haven't been able to find any information if they can be changed via some API. The settings are in ProjectFolder -> ProjectSettings. If this is what you were looking for. What do you mean by decent result, why changing active monitor didn't work?

Comment: @CandidMoon Yeah, neither have I. I know you can use command line arguments to set the settings so it's clearly possible to have similar functionality to the dialog, but I just couldn't find if it's possible to reroute the game to take them from a file at launch. When I use the SetActiveMonitor on another monitor, it just turns it black without disabling the first one or shifting the camera to the second. When I disable the first monitor, the second just stays black. I also tried moving the screenspace via the win api, but that's a big problem if you have  monitors with different resolutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79801/discussion-between-candid-moon-and-paul-vinogradov).